# Forming exact sequences from monomorphisms in abelian categories

Tags: abelian-categories

Suppose I have a monomoprhism $f:A\to B$ of abelian groups. Then, the sequence $O\rightarrow A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B$ is exact and the sequence $O\rightarrow A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B\rightarrow B/f(A)\rightarrow 0$ is short exact sequence.

Can I do something similar if I have exact sequence $0\to A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B$ in abelian category, can I obtain short exact sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism in an abelian category.
Then we have an exact sequence
$$\mathrm O\to\operatorname{Ker} f\xrightarrow{\ker f}A\xrightarrow fB\xrightarrow{\operatorname{cok}f}\operatorname{Cok}f\to\mathrm O$$
where $\operatorname{Ker} f\xrightarrow{\ker f}A$ and $B\xrightarrow{\operatorname{cok}f}\operatorname{Cok}(f)$ denote, respectively, a kernel and a [cokernel](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel) of $f$.

Then $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $\operatorname{Ker}f\cong\mathrm O$ and in that case we get your exact sequence
$$\mathrm O\to A\xrightarrow fB\xrightarrow{\operatorname{cok}f}\operatorname{Cok}f\to\mathrm O$$

Dually, $f$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\operatorname{Cok}f\cong\mathrm O$, and in that case we get an exact sequence
$$\mathrm O\to\operatorname{Ker} f\xrightarrow{\ker f}A\xrightarrow fB\to\mathrm O$$

More generally, a sequence
$$\mathrm O\to K\xrightarrow k M\xrightarrow p P$$
is exact if and only if $k$ is a kernel of $p$, while 
$$K\xrightarrow k M\xrightarrow p P\to\mathrm O$$
is exact if and only if $p$ is a cokernel of $k$.